# BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::merge does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

getting  **BadMethodCallException, Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::merge does not exist.** when trying to execute the following

```
public function getFriends1()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Friend', 'friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
}

public function getFriends2()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Friend', 'friends', 'friend_id', 'user_id');
}

public function getFriends()
{
    return $this->getFriends1()->merge($this->getFriends2());
}
```

Comment: why are you trying to call `merge` on a builder, what do you think `getFriends1` returns?  hint hint, it is not a collection

Comment: what about getting data as an array and merging them using `array_merge` ?

Comment: [Laravel 5.6 Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Relationship Methods vs Dynamic Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)

Comment: what does it return ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "->get()" to defined relationships:

```
public function getFriends()
{
    $friends1= $this->belongsToMany('App\Friend', 'friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id')->get();
    $friends2= $this->belongsToMany('App\Friend', 'friends', 'friend_id', 'user_id')->get();
    return $friends1->merge($friends2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two things that you can do:

```
// Option 1
public function getFriends()
{
    return $this->getFriends1->merge($this->getFriends2);
}

// Option 2
public function getFriends()
{
    return $this->getFriends1()->get()->merge($this->getFriends2->get());
}
```

Comment: already tried option 1.

option 2 gave me the following error:
 Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42000)
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'friends' (SQL: select `friends`.*, `friends`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `friends`.`friend_id` as `pivot_friend_id` from `friends` inner join `friends` on `friends`.`id` = `friends`.`friend_id` where `friends`.`user_id` = 2)